# Python sum values by daterange

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have list with a pair of a timestamp/datetime and a value given by my mongodb.
(The data from the mongodb are organized as follows:)

```
"timestamp" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
realPower" : {
        "0" : {
            "0": 545.5,
            "15" : 614.5,
            "30" : 586.25,
            "45" : 565.75
        },
        "1" : {
            "0" : 574.5,
            "15" : 549.5,
            "30" : 564,
            "45" : 545.75
        },
    ( … )
        "22" : {
            "0" : 604.75,
            "15" : 605,
            "30" : 605,
            "45" : 605
        },
        "23" : {
            "0" : 604.75,
            "15" : 605,
            "30" : 605,
            "45" : 604.5
        }
    }
}
```

I've transformed the mongodb items to the following list

list items (one day):

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 0), 545.5]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 15), 614.5]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 30), 586.25]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 45), 565.75]
(...)
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 23, 45), 604.5]
```

I have a method which will generate a nice interval for my data:

```
def date_span(start_date, end_date, data):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=15)
    current_date = start_date.replace(minute=0)
    while current_date < end_date:
        yield current_date
        current_date += delta
```

However, how to combine and sum the data of list items with the new timespan items? I would like to summarize the values by the given time. E.g. summarize the values for each hour, each day, each week, each month, each year. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the data is currently stored is not really helping you here. You would be better off taking your "transform" one step further and storing data that way:

```js
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "realPower": 545.5 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:15:00.000Z"), "realPower": 614.5 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:30:00.000Z"), "realPower": 586.25 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:45:00.000Z"), "realPower": 565.75 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T01:00:00.000Z"), "realPower": 574.5 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T01:15:00.000Z"), "realPower": 549.5 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T01:30:00.000Z"), "realPower": 564 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T01:45:00.000Z"), "realPower": 545.75 }
{ ... }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"), "realPower": 604.75 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T23:15:00.000Z"), "realPower": 605 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T23:30:00.000Z"), "realPower": 605 }
{ "timestamp": ISODate("2014-01-01T23:45:00.000Z"), "realPower": 604.5 }
```

The reason being that the "sub-document" structure you presently have does not translate well to server side aggregation methods. That really has to do with "part of your data" being represented as a "key", which is not a very good pattern to follow.

There are cases for structuring with a "sub-document" representing an interval, but usually these involve keeping "buckets" of discrete values within a specific interval, and the main point there is to avoid "nested arrays" which are generally bad for updates.

But in the proposed form your queries are a simple matter of applying the [aggregation framework](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate). There are [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) available there to handle grouping in specific intervals:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match documents between dates
    { "$match": { 
        "timestamp": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate }
    }},
    // Group by hour
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$timestamp" },
            "month": { "$month": "$timestamp" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$timestamp" }
        },
        "avgPower": { "$avg": "$realPower" }
    }}
])
```

Where essentially you define a "grouping key" out of your timestamp value and for the other value(s) you want in results you apply any of the [Group accumulator operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/)s, in this case the average.

Alternately to using the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) you could also convert your date object to an epoch timestamp value, and apply the date math for intervals. Where `epochDate` here is a date object passed as an argument representing "1970-01-01" which is the 0 epoch date:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    //Match documents between dates
    { "$match": { 
        "timestamp": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate }
    }},
    //Group by day: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = milliseconds in a day
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    "$timestamp", epochDate
                ]},
                { "$mod": [
                    { "$subtract": [
                        "$timestamp", epochDate
                    ]},
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "sumPower": { "$sum": "$realPower" }
    }}
])
```

Where the resulting timestamp values can be fed back into a date object if that is what you require. The trick here is that doing something like "subtracting" one date object from another results in the difference in milliseconds represented as a number.

---

With the current structure however you are looking a JavaScript processing with [mapReduce](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce) to process this on the server side. This will happen much slower due to the need to "interpret" the code.

So in a mapper, grouping per month for the "sum"

```js
function() {
    var values = [];

    var realPower = this.realPower;
    for ( var k in realPower ) {
        for ( var i in k ) {
            values.push( realPower[k][i] );
        }
    }

    emit(
        { 
            "year": this.timestamp.getFullYear(),
            "month": this.timestamp.getMonth() + 1
        },
        { "values": values }
    );
}
```

And then a reducer:

```js
function(key,values) {
    var result = { "values": [] };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        value.values.forEach(function(item) {
            result.values.push( item );
        }
    }
}
```

And handle the "sum" in a finalize function in case there was only a singula keys emitted for a given grouping:

```js
function(key,value) {

    return Array.sum( value.values );

}
```

And invoke the mapReduce with a query :

```python
results = db.collection.inline_map_reduce(
    map,
    reduce, 
    query={ "timestamp": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate } },
    finalize=finalize
)
```

So generally a bit uglier and certainly slower. As you see in the "mapper" definition, the "sub-document" structure needs to be traversed or otherwise have "specific" keys picked out, such as would be the case in accumulating per hour.

---

In either case, the server side processing is generally the way that you want to go as your database server is most likely to have more grunt than your application server, or at least that should be the case.

Try to go with changing the data structure. The rewards for querying and further aggregation outweigh the cost of the one time data manipulation.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer. In relation to the data structure: I found this [post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) which described how to store time-series with mongodb. If I create a document for each value, I don't need mongodb here? I thought, organizing the sets of data per day would speed up my queries, because I'm only looking for date-ranges in days.

Comment: @wiesson Yes and no as to the speed up, but it is generally all relative. Without looking I already know that the link you refer to is actually based on part of the construction of the MMS monitoring service. The intent there is to "bucket" discrete values without nested arrays. Your data does not appear to match that pattern, and creating single documents for each entry would seem to be the better option. There is always the mapReduce option if you cannot or do not want to change.

Comment: I'm currently comparing your suggested approach with the one I did before. The insert / update speed is nearly the same and it also has advantages, I can easily add more information such as comments to a specific value.